# How to Generify REST Controller in Spring MVC to Remove Duplication

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, annotations, code-duplication

I have a design issue I cannot for the life of me figure out.
Good code has no duplication. I have generified my DAO so all basic crud operations are inherited
I'm trying to do the same with Spring MVC with Annotated Controllers.

I found this question but no answer is there: [How to Remove Duplication from Spring 3 MVC Standard and Ajax Request Controllers and Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621945/how-to-remove-duplication-from-spring-3-mvc-standard-and-ajax-request-controller)

If I have something like the below example, assuming I refactor to use AbstractBaseService and BaseModel (I did this but don't have the code), how can I put the annotation info into something like a GenericAbstractBaseController or BaseController interface? I've tried (don't have the code here) but the problem is that Annotations ARE NOT inherited and CANNOT be added at run time.

I see that javassist can be used for bytecode modification so that I actually CAN add annotations after compiling to keep the code clean but this appears to be overly complex.

I sent a note to a mentor and he suggested using AOP with naming convention to weave advice or reflection to identify the annotations from the inherited class but I'm not certain how I could actually give this info to spring given that I cannot actually add annotations at runtime. I think I'm missing some critical key here that someone will come and drop - he only sent me back a couple lines.

Here is the code - how can I remove the duplicate crud logic.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody  List<User> doGetIndex(ModelMap model) {
    return userService.listPage(0, 10);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User doGet(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {
    return userService.getByUsername(name);
}

//post

//put

//delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what do you mean by "annotations are not inherited", but as far as I remember the following approach should work:

```
public class AbstractController<T> {
    @RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody  List<User> doGetIndex(ModelMap model) { ... }

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody T doGet(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) { ... }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController extends AbstractController<User> { ... }
```

Comment: Does that work? I didn't think the annotations were inherited. I'll try again. I have a generic abstract controller like that - I'll try again and post it later - thanks.